# Conditional page for logged user (Member Only Page)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make my wordpress site hidden or restricted from guest user. Only the the registered member will see my pages, if they are not registered then they will be redirected in login page/ registration page.

When i am tried to use some plugin to do that then all of my pages restricted and there had option to exclude only one page (login page). But i guest cant register there. Because all of the page restricted excluding loging page. SO thats a problem.

Now i think i can use custom code something like that

`<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
echo 'Welcome, registered user!';} else {  echo 'You have no rights to access this page. Please <a href=\"#\">log in</a> or a href=\"#\">register</a> now to access that page';
}
?>`

But how can i set a function , "If logged in then full page will open other wise show a text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the content, then you can use the_content hook to change the page content for not loggedin user.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'restricted_content');
function restricted_content($content)
{
    if( !is_user_logged_in()
    {
        $content = 'You have no rights to access this page...blah blah..';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Now, if the login/registration is a General WordPress Page created using WP Admin, you can either exclude it by id, name or slug.

```
function restricted_content($content)
{
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page('login') && ! is_page('registration') // an id or name can be passed also
    {
        $content = 'You have no rights to access this page...blah blah..';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: WC. yes functions.php

Comment: try debugging, get the error message. Probably there's already another function named `restricted_content` . And you need to use the function once. I wrote it twice here to show the difference.